# getType does not match an Integer with an Integer from a jObject

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I'm building a settings storage bit, and I recently migrated from a huge mess of if-else to a generic solution. However, the GetType parser appears to fail on the first entry in json, but the rest seem to go through.

Now, when I've tested the simplified code, none of them work. I do box the item to object, but does this mean any attempted unboxing will be the JValue and not based on what is in the JValue?

The json is:

```
{
  "SectorSizePerSide": 10,
  "DefaultStellarPrefix": "ISC",
  "DefaultSystemPrefix": "UNKS",
  "DefaultSectorPrefix": "GS",
  "GridType": 3,
  "StellarDensity": 0.04,
  "MinimumStellarSeperation": 1.1,
  "MaxSizeOfSystemCatalog": 100000,
  "MaxSizeOfSectorCatalog": 50000,
  "MaxSizeOfStellarCatalog": 10000000,
  "AdditionalGeneration": 2,
  "LightYearResolution": 10,
  "TwoDMultiplication": 10,
  "AllowForSpaceOperaOverride": false,
  "InterstellarNebulaThreshold": 9999.03,
  "PlanetaryNebulaThreshold": .005,
  "AllowNegativeGrid" : false
}
```

EDIT: This is the struct the code is being deseralized into:

```
protected Dictionary<System.Enum, object> Properties = new Dictionary<System.Enum, object>();
```

I extend the base class so I can specify the Enum (which is PropertyName) here.

As for simplifying the code, I'm rather worried part of it is because I'm using multiples. But a standard example of the validation code is using a Dictionary with the enum of the first paramater, and a delegate that returns true/false, and takes an object (To make it generic). Usually it's within two numbers, so it calls a function that compares them, returns true in range and false otherwise.

EDIT2: Here's a trimmed down variant of the code - doesn't have the original validation controls, because the problem doesn't appear to be there.

```
  private delegate bool ValidationDelegate(object o);

  var ourValidators = new Dictionary<PropertyName, ValidationDelegate>()
  {
      {PropertyName.StellarDensity, (o) => { if (o.GetType() == typeof(double)) return true; return false; }},
      {PropertyName.GridType, (o) => { if (o.GetType() == typeof(int)) return true; return false; }},
      {PropertyName.MinimumStellarSeperation, (o) => { if (o.GetType() == typeof(double)) return true; return false; }},
   }

   public void LoadProperties()
   {
         using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(base.FilePath))
         {
             JObject rawInput = JObject.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());
             foreach (var entry in rawInput)
             {
               try
               {
                  PropertyName thisProperty = genHelper.parseEnum<PropertyName>(entry.Key);
                  if (ourValidators[thisProperty](entry.Value.Value<object>()))
                     this.Set(thisProperty, entry.Value.Value<object>());
                  else
                     settingInvalidSet<object>(thisProperty, ourDefaults[thisProperty]);

                 }
           }
      }
```

Comment: Please show the class or struct into which you are deserializing this. Most people aren't going to look at your github link.

Comment: Also, can  you please narrow this down? I looked at your code, and it's fairly complex. Try to narrow this down to a simple deserialization scenario.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I'm not really sure how to simplify it without reverting to a different approach. I did edit the code in, though. I should note that InterstellarNebula is knowingly incorrect. I was testing the failure code.

Comment: Added a simplified version of the code.

Comment: Thanks for the simplification. Now what's the actual _problem_? Validator succeeds when it shouldn't? Which one?

Comment: The problem appears to be that the first entry in the json file fails GetType. The rest succeed fine. This persists if you change the first entry of the json file.

Comment: You should really be able to single-step it now and find out what the problem is. In particular, what is the return value of GetType when it fails?

Comment: GetType apparently is now always reporting Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue. Weird. I *know* I had the casting working. I mean, I guess I should go replace it with .TryConvert.